# Campaign Tracking Android using EasyTracker

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I want to implement Campaign Tracking in my application using EasyTracker
I have [this link for help](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#general-tracking)
I cant understand how do I got `EasyTracker.getInstance()`
Is there some Jar which I have to add in my project? for geting EasyTracker Instance
If so then please tell me from where I can get that jar?
I have found source code of `EasyTrackerSrcAndroid_1.0.zip` from [this link](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/downloads/detail?name=EasyTrackerSrcAndroid_1.0.zip&can=2&q=)
But this code is not working as mention in above link which I am following for help.
Such as this code dosent have `EasyTracker.getInstance().setContext(this);` and `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart` and `EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop` and `EasyTracker.getTracker().setCampaign(uri.getPath())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4693469/EasyTracker.jar

Comment: Thanks Georgy Gobozov but still i didn't find these functions 
"EasyTracker.getTracker().activityStop(this);
EasyTracker.getTracker().activityStart(this);
EasyTracker.getTracker().setCampaign(uri.getPath());"
i have to implement these function calls or not??
because i see these in link which i am following

Comment: use EasyTracker.getTracker() more information http://analytics-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadocs/index.html?com/google/android/apps/analytics/easytracking/EasyTracker.html

Comment: do not use EasyTracker in onCreate method

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The solution:

Remove EasyTracker.jar from your project. You won't need that anymore since the new analytics v2 api came out. Add the libgoogleanalyticsv2.jar library to your libs folder and add it to your project build path.

you are ready to go!